# Exception while reading file from SD Card

Tags: android, android-sdcard, ioexception

I am trying to read an XML file from the SD card. The path is fine, but it says:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/mnt/sdcard/Reginfo/output/data.xml (No such file or directory)

Here is how I am attempting to read this file:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("file://"
                    + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/RegInfo/output/data.xml"));
```

I can see this file in the `sdCard/RegInfo/output` folder in File Explorer.

Comment: have you added READ permission in manifest.xml file ?

Comment: this permission is added --->  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `"file://"` from path...

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                    + "/RegInfo/output/data.xml"));
```

Only using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()`, you will get the `SDCard` directory. Theres no need to add `"file://"` before path.